Open-XChange 7.10.6 and Univention 5.0.8 not working after installing OX-Connector
I've been using UCS (Univention Corporate Server) version 4.4 for some time.
After a couple of years of applying the recommended updates, we moved to the 5.x version.
Everything was working until we changed version of Open-XChange, one of the modules offered by UCS, to version 7.10.6, where the need is to install OX-Connector. 
Starting with this version, all the users declared or modified from the AD (a Windows Domain Controller) that previously worked like a charm, are being synchronized on the UCS server, but not available on the OX module, even trying to deactivate and reactivate the OX App Suite for that user. 
That user in fact was created on the UCS server, and can send and receive emails using a typical client such as Thunderbird, but cannot make use of the calendar, contacts, tasks, drive, etc. offered by OX. 
When trying to log into the OX App Suite using the "test4" user, created and working from Thunderbird for email only, I receive this error on the open-xchange.log.0 file (changed the server and domain name to myserver.mydomain.com): 

2024-09-16T00:55:36,574-0300 INFO  [OXWorker-0007563] com.openexchange.login.internal.LoginPerformer.logLoginRequest(LoginPerformer.java:722)
Login:test4 IP:10.1.1.60 AuthID:69bd382cc6b04f9aaef5c7bc31307783 Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0 Client:open-xchange-appsuite(7.10.6-20) Interface:HTTP_JSON No session created.
com.openexchange.database.schema=localhost_5
com.openexchange.grizzly.method=POST
com.openexchange.grizzly.queryString=
com.openexchange.grizzly.remoteAddress=10.1.1.60
com.openexchange.grizzly.remotePort=34094
com.openexchange.grizzly.requestURI=/ajax/login
com.openexchange.grizzly.serverName=myserver.mydomain.com
com.openexchange.grizzly.servletPath=/ajax/login
com.openexchange.grizzly.session=4100505390927467743.OX0
com.openexchange.grizzly.threadName=OXWorker-0007563
com.openexchange.grizzly.userAgent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0
com.openexchange.localhost.ipAddress=10.1.1.29
com.openexchange.localhost.version=7.10.6-Rev22
com.openexchange.login.authId=69bd382cc6b04f9aaef5c7bc31307783
com.openexchange.login.client=open-xchange-appsuite
com.openexchange.login.clientIp=10.1.1.60
com.openexchange.login.login=test4
com.openexchange.login.userAgent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0
com.openexchange.login.version=7.10.6-20
com.openexchange.request.trackingId=1745491699-872910835
2024-09-16T00:55:36,575-0300 ERROR [OXWorker-0007563] com.openexchange.ajax.login.AbstractLoginRequestHandler.loginOperation(AbstractLoginRequestHandler.java:375)
com.openexchange.database.schema=localhost_5
com.openexchange.grizzly.method=POST
com.openexchange.grizzly.queryString=
com.openexchange.grizzly.remoteAddress=10.1.1.60
com.openexchange.grizzly.remotePort=34094
com.openexchange.grizzly.requestURI=/ajax/login
com.openexchange.grizzly.serverName=myserver.mydomain.com
com.openexchange.grizzly.servletPath=/ajax/login
com.openexchange.grizzly.session=4100505390927467743.OX0
com.openexchange.grizzly.threadName=OXWorker-0007563
com.openexchange.grizzly.userAgent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0
com.openexchange.localhost.ipAddress=10.1.1.29
com.openexchange.localhost.version=7.10.6-Rev22
com.openexchange.login.authId=69bd382cc6b04f9aaef5c7bc31307783
com.openexchange.login.client=open-xchange-appsuite
com.openexchange.login.clientIp=10.1.1.60
com.openexchange.login.login=test4
com.openexchange.login.userAgent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0
com.openexchange.login.version=7.10.6-20
com.openexchange.request.trackingId=1745491699-872910835
com.openexchange.exception.OXException: USR-0015 Categories=ERROR Message='Cannot find user with identifier test4 in context 10.' exceptionID=1745491699-101116
at com.openexchange.exception.OXExceptionFactory.create(OXExceptionFactory.java:154)
at com.openexchange.exception.OXExceptionFactory.create(OXExceptionFactory.java:144)
at com.openexchange.exception.OXExceptionFactory.create(OXExceptionFactory.java:117)
at com.openexchange.groupware.ldap.LdapExceptionCode.create(LdapExceptionCode.java:205)
at com.openexchange.groupware.ldap.RdbUserStorage.getUserId(RdbUserStorage.java:150)
at com.openexchange.groupware.ldap.CachingUserStorage.getUserId(CachingUserStorage.java:521)
at com.openexchange.login.internal.LoginPerformer.findUser(LoginPerformer.java:464)
at com.openexchange.login.internal.LoginPerformer.doLogin(LoginPerformer.java:242)
at com.openexchange.login.internal.LoginPerformer.doLogin(LoginPerformer.java:132)
at com.openexchange.login.internal.LoginPerformer.doLogin(LoginPerformer.java:120)
at com.openexchange.ajax.login.Login$1.doLogin(Login.java:82)
at com.openexchange.ajax.login.AbstractLoginRequestHandler.loginOperation(AbstractLoginRequestHandler.java:236)
at com.openexchange.ajax.login.AbstractLoginRequestHandler.loginOperation(AbstractLoginRequestHandler.java:194)
at com.openexchange.ajax.login.Login.doLogin(Login.java:70)
at com.openexchange.ajax.login.Login.handleRequest(Login.java:62)
at com.openexchange.ajax.LoginServlet.doJSONAuth(LoginServlet.java:877)
at com.openexchange.ajax.LoginServlet.doGet(LoginServlet.java:815)
at com.openexchange.ajax.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:955)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:706)
at com.openexchange.ajax.AJAXServlet.doService(AJAXServlet.java:557)
at com.openexchange.ajax.LoginServlet.service(LoginServlet.java:788)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:124)
at com.openexchange.http.grizzly.servletfilter.RequestReportingFilter.doFilter(RequestReportingFilter.java:109)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:114)
at com.openexchange.http.grizzly.servletfilter.WrappingFilter.doFilter(WrappingFilter.java:195)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:114)
at com.openexchange.http.grizzly.service.http.OSGiAuthFilter.doFilter(OSGiAuthFilter.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.FilterChainImpl.invokeFilterChain(FilterChainImpl.java:83)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletHandler.doServletService(ServletHandler.java:202)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletHandler.service(ServletHandler.java:154)
at com.openexchange.http.grizzly.service.http.OSGiMainHandler.doHttpService(OSGiMainHandler.java:302)
at com.openexchange.http.grizzly.service.http.OSGiMainHandler.service(OSGiMainHandler.java:263)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler$1.run(HttpHandler.java:200)
at com.openexchange.threadpool.internal.CustomThreadPoolExecutor$MDCProvidingRunnable.run(CustomThreadPoolExecutor.java:2593)
at com.openexchange.threadpool.internal.CustomThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(CustomThreadPoolExecutor.java:806)
at com.openexchange.threadpool.internal.CustomThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(CustomThreadPoolExecutor.java:833)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)


Looks like it's not connecting to some LDAP but I really don't know which one, or where to start checking. 
Checked on the Univention site, but nothing looks like this kind of issue. 
Any help will be really appreciated!
Thanks a lot in advance, and best regards!
HeCSa.
